# Error Code: 2014 Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Tags: mysql, sql

While I was testing a trigger that I wrote , I got this error
"Error Code: 2014 Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now"

```
create trigger training_session_is_full 
    before insert on acq_training_enrolment
    for each row
begin

    DECLARE max_number_of_enrolment INT;
    DECLARE current_number_of_enrolment INT;    
    DECLARE temp_staff_id INT;
    DECLARE temp_course_id INT;
    DECLARE msg VARCHAR(255);
    
    SELECT acq_person_id INTO temp_staff_id FROM acq_staff WHERE acq_person_id = NEW.staff_id;
    SELECT training_course_session_id INTO temp_course_id FROM acq_training_coruse_session WHERE training_course_session_id = NEW.course_id;
    SELECT max_number_of_attendees INTO max_number_of_enrolment FROM acq_training_course_session;
    SELECT count(training_enrolment_id) INTO current_number_of_enrolment FROM acq_training_enrolment;

    IF(max_number_of_enrolment == current_number_of_enrolment) OR 
    temp_staff_id != NEW.staff_id OR
    temp_course_id != NEW.course_id OR
    temp_staff_id IN (SELECT * FROM acq_training_enrolment WHERE acq_staff_acq_person_id = NEW.staffID)
    THEN 
    SET msg = '-1';
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = msg;
    END IF;
    
end
```

But I can't find what is incorrect or wrong.

Any advice please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You aren't setting delimiters https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html, null safe equal in mysql is <=> not == see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html and the end statement is not terminated.

```
delimiter $$
create trigger raining_session_is_full 
before insert on acq_training_enrolment
    for each row
begin

    DECLARE max_number_of_enrolment INT;
    DECLARE current_number_of_enrolment INT;    
    DECLARE temp_staff_id INT;
    DECLARE temp_course_id INT;
    DECLARE msg VARCHAR(255);
    
    SELECT acq_person_id INTO temp_staff_id FROM acq_staff WHERE acq_person_id = NEW.staff_id;
    SELECT training_course_session_id INTO temp_course_id FROM acq_training_coruse_session WHERE training_course_session_id = NEW.course_id;
    SELECT max_number_of_attendees INTO max_number_of_enrolment FROM acq_training_course_session;
    SELECT count(training_enrolment_id) INTO current_number_of_enrolment FROM acq_training_enrolment;

    IF(max_number_of_enrolment <=> current_number_of_enrolment) OR 
    temp_staff_id != NEW.staff_id OR
    temp_course_id != NEW.course_id OR
    temp_staff_id IN (SELECT * FROM acq_training_enrolment WHERE acq_staff_acq_person_id = NEW.staffID)
    THEN 
    SET msg = '-1';
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = msg;
    END IF;
    
end $$

delimiter ;
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment! 

for null safe equal, should I change`max_number_of_enrolment == current_number_of_enrolment` this part?

And I don't actually understand how to terminate end statement :( 

Can I ask little more advice please??

Thank you so much tho!!

Comment: See edit. Still having problems?add table definitions as text..

Comment: Yes I changed `==` to `<=>` and added DELIMITER .but still having error :( 
I'm so sorry but where should I add table definitions..?

Comment: Add to the question using edit button. Also tell us what UI your are using (if any) and how/where you are creating the trigger.